# separating propositons with commas?

Tags: logic

From [Kaye's Mathematics Logic](http://books.google.com/books?id=EOjT_j-qOnsC&lpg=PA70&ots=zYU7MVgVkP&dq=Another%20place%20where%20we%20relax%20notation%20is%20in%20the%20notation%20on%20the%20left%20hand%20side%20of%20a%20turnstile%20symbol&pg=PA70#v=onepage&q=Another%20place%20where%20we%20relax%20notation%20is%20in%20the%20notation%20on%20the%20left%20hand%20side%20of%20a%20turnstile%20symbol&f=false), about notation for propositional logic:

> Another place where we relax notation is in the notation on **the left hand
>   side of a turnstile symbol** $\vdash$. Instead of using set theory notation with $\{\ldots\}, \cup,
> ∅$, etc., it is traditional to list formulas and sets of formulas, **separating them
>   with commas**, and regard the list as a single set of formulas, so the order of
>   formulas in the list and any repetitions in it is ignored. This applies to both
>   the turnstile $\vdash$ of this chapter and the turnstile that will be introduced in the
>   next. Thus, with all the conventions in place, the previous example would be
>   written as $a ∧ b \vdash ¬(¬ a ∨ ¬ b)$. The empty set is written as an empty list, as in $\vdash (a ∨ ¬ a)$.

1. Does "separating them with commas" mean to represent $a ∧ b \vdash
       ¬(¬ a ∨ ¬ b)$ as $a, b \vdash ¬(¬ a ∨ ¬ b)$ ? Then what is the
   difference between  $a ∧ b$  and $a, b$ ?

   I can't figure out what the paragraph is saying from the two
   examples.
2. Also [a propositional language doesn't have comma as a
   punctuation symbol](http://books.google.com/books?id=EOjT_j-qOnsC&lpg=PA70&ots=zYU7MVgVkP&dq=Another%20place%20where%20we%20relax%20notation%20is%20in%20the%20notation%20on%20the%20left%20hand%20side%20of%20a%20turnstile%20symbol&pg=PA64#v=onepage&q&f=false), while [a first order language does](http://books.google.com/books?id=EOjT_j-qOnsC&lpg=PA70&ots=zYU7MVgVkP&dq=Another%20place%20where%20we%20relax%20notation%20is%20in%20the%20notation%20on%20the%20left%20hand%20side%20of%20a%20turnstile%20symbol&pg=PA117#v=onepage&q&f=false). Is it true?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, I think in this case it turns out that $\{a \land b\}$ and $\{a,b\}$ are equivalent, but I imagine the author meant that you write $a \land b \vdash ...$ instead of $\{ a \land b \} \vdash ...$?

Comment: (1) First of all, by $\{a∧b\}$ do you mean it is a set? why is the LHS a set? Isn't it a boolean term? (2) WHere is "comma"?

Comment: I think this was very badly explained. I agree with copper.at, the author means that instead of writing $\{\varphi _1, \ldots ,\varphi_n\}\vdash \text{Whatever}$, you can write $\varphi _1, \ldots ,\varphi_n\vdash \text{Whatever}$.

Comment: I mean a set of formulae. If the author's example was $a \lor b$ then you would write $a \lor b \vdash ...$. It just so happens that in this particular example we have $a \land b \vdash ...$ is equivalent to $a,b \vdash ...$.

Comment: @Git: (1) why is the LHS a set? I think it is a boolean term, not a set. (2)since we have $∧$, why do we need comma?

Comment: @copper.hat, I see one formula, not a set of formulas on the LHS?

Comment: @Tim Most likely that book formalizes things within $\sf ZFC$ (implicitly). Or they don't want to think about that and they just expect you to accept that something like $\{a\land b\}$ is a set with a boolean term in it. I'm a bit confused by your second question, can you reformulate it?

Comment: @Git: (1) WHat does "a set of formulas on the LHS of the turnstile symbol" mean? "AND" of the formulas, or "OR" of the formulas, or ...? (2) Does a comma between formulas mean "AND" of the formulas?

Comment: @Tim You can't separate the LHS from the RHS. Given a set of formulas $\Sigma$ and $\varphi$ another formula. The sequence of symbols $\Sigma \vdash \varphi$ means that from $\Sigma$ there is a formal proof whose last symbol is $\varphi$.You can interpret the commas as conjunctions only because it actually happens that $\{\varphi _1, \ldots ,\varphi_n\}\vdash \varphi\iff \{\varphi _1\land \ldots \land\varphi_n\}\vdash \varphi$, but this is something which can be proved. The sequence of symbols $\{\varphi _1, \ldots ,\varphi_n\}\vdash \varphi$ is meaningful by itself.

Comment: @copper.hat  what does "mistake trail" mean?

Comment: @Tim: I often add a comment without a huge amount of thought (think of it as a mathematical Tourette's syndrome). While I never intend to write something incorrect, it often is. However, I (perhaps incorrectly) think it may help others by providing one approach to a problem. (This was not the case here.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "official" notation is :

> $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$

where :

> $\Gamma = \{ φ_1,\ldots,φ_n \}$.

The "abbreviation" licenses us to write it as :

> > $φ_1,\ldots,φ_n \vdash φ$.

Also, when $\Gamma = \emptyset$, instead of :

> $\emptyset \vdash \varphi$

we will write :

> $\vdash \varphi$.

Another abbreviation is the following :

> $\Gamma, \alpha \vdash \varphi$

in place of the "official" :

> $\Gamma \cup \{ \alpha \} \vdash \varphi$.

---

*Comment*

Regarding the example discussed, it must be :

> $\{ a∧b \} \vdash a$

abbreviated as :

> $a∧b \vdash a$

and not : $a, b \vdash a$.

We have to note an important distinction: that between *object language* and *meta-language*.

In the *formal system* of propositional logic, assuming that the propositional letters are the $p_i$'s, we have that e.g. $p_1 \land p_2$ is a formula.

The symbol :

$\Gamma \vdash \varphi$

is **not** part of the formal system. It is part of the meta-language, and says that there is a *derivation* (i.e.a *sequence* of formulae of the system satisfying certain rules) of the formula $\varphi$ from the assumptions in $\Gamma$.

Thus, when we license ourselves to "abbreviate" :

> $\{p \rightarrow q, q \rightarrow r \} \vdash p \rightarrow r$

as :

> $p \rightarrow q, q \rightarrow r \vdash p \rightarrow r$

we are introducing an abbreviation in the metalanguage.

---

*Added*

About commas in f-o logic : yes, we need it for *terms*, written as :

> $f_i(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$

where $f_i$ is the $i$-th function letter (in the enumeration of the *alphabet*) and has $n$ argument-places.

If we choose to make explicit the number of arguments, writing : $f_i^n$, we can avoid comma and parentheses, writing terms as :

> $f_i^nx_1 \ldots x_n$.